# Conditionally place item within grid layout

Tags: html, css, reactjs, typescript

I have a few scenarios in my grid. I have 4 possible grid elements, but depending on a user selection from the previous screen, I might only display three of those.

I'm running into an issue where in a particular circumstance, I want to display only 3 elements (2 per row), with the third element on the bottom row placed to the far right, essentially leaving an empty space where the first element of the second row normally would be.

```
const MyGrid = styled(OtherGrid)`
  @media (max-width: ${BP.SMALL - 1}px) {
    div:nth-child(2) {
      grid-row-start: 3;
    }
    div:nth-child(3) {
      grid-row-start: 2;
    }
  }
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
`;
```

My grid is styled from another grid, but all in all, acts like a basic grid.

```
<MyGrid>
        <FormGroup
          type={"number"}
          name={"initial_moisture"}
          label={"Initial Moisture (%)"}
          step={0.1}
          required
        />
        <FormGroup
          type={"number"}
          name={"initial_temp"}
          label={`Initial Temperature (${isMetric ? "C" : "F"})`}
          step={1}
          required
        />
        {operatingMode != "auto_cool" && (
          <>
            <FormGroup
              type={"number"}
              name={"final_moisture"}
              label={"Target Moisture (%)"}
              step={0.1}
              required
            />
          </>
        )}
        {operatingMode != "auto_hydrate" && (
          <>
            <FormGroup
              class={"auto-cool"}
              type={"number"}
              name={"final_temp"}
              label={`Target Temperature (${isMetric ? "C" : "F"})`}
              step={1}
              required
            />
          </>
        )}
</MyGrid>
```

In the last possible state here (operatingMode != "auto-hydrate"), I want to place that element on the second row, but in the second column as well, and leave an empty space on the 2nd row, first column. Is there something within my parent container GoalsFieldGrid that I can define that will help me do this?
`grid-column: -1;` is what I'm looking for, but I'm not sure how to apply it in that specific scenario.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you only require this when there are three elements only.

That being the case you can use `:nth-child(3):last-child` to select the element.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  gap: .25em;
}

.item {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 1em;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

.item:nth-child(3):last-child {
  grid-column: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well, there is a scenario where I display only 3 elements but the third is kept on the first 2nd row, first column. The other scenario is my issue, where there are still only the elements, but I need it placed like you depicted above.

I'm just trying to keep them lined up like so as the Form Fields on the top and bottom rows are related.

Comment: Ahh, scratch everything. Changing from `grid-column: -1;` to `grid-column: 2` fixed it. I wonder why it didn't like the -1? It made my layout wonky.